# Why is var let = variable allowed?

Tags: javascript

Playing in the chrome console I've found out that you can assign a variable to the keyword "let", but only using var. Is there a reason for this choice, or some bug that if fixed will break more stuff, like fixing null to not be Object?

```js
const let = 'asd'; // Error
let let = 'asd'; // Error
```

But the below snippet works.

```js
var let = () => 5;
let();
```

Comment: `let` was not a reserved word when it was added, so it's allowed so that old code doesn't suddenly break.

Comment: Wow, it's been asked before. I probably should have known that, but... :-)